# Filter out Strings from an Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a problem I'm facing in Javascript, I am totally new to JS. This is my code:

```js
    function filterOutStringfromArr(array) {
        var arr = []
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (typeof array[i] === 'number') {
                arr[i] = array[i]
            }
        }
        console.log(arr)
    }
    filterOutStringfromArr([1,2,'A','B',123])
```

when I run this, I get this result: `[ 1, 2, <2 empty items>, 123 ]`.

I know this is happening because the length of my array is 5. But I want to append just the filtered value to the empty array `arr[]`. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `arr.push()` instead of `arr[i] = `.

Comment: you can use filter function to achieve the same

Comment: @sirko when i try to arr.push() it just add the last element to empty array

Comment: @bair isnt that what you asked for? `I want to append just the filtered value to the empty array` To me that reads add the found item to the last element in the array. Are you looking for something different?

Comment: @gh9 i got my answer dear . thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
function filterOutStringfromArr(array) {
    var arr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (typeof array[i] === 'number') {
          arr.push(array[i])
        }
    }
    console.log(arr)
}
filterOutStringfromArr([1,2,'A','B',123])
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) link that is pretty good

You should use `push` that will append to the end of an array. By inserting the found element into spot `i` you are going from index 3 to 5 thus the empty elements.

Comment: @bari no worries glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method.

```js
function filterOutStringsfromArray(array) {
    var arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (typeof array[i] === 'string') {
          arr.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

filterOutStringfromArr([5, 2, 'h', 2, 's', 2]) // Expected Output: ['h', 's']
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter method will solve your issue.

```js
function filterOutStringfromArr(array) {
    const newArray = array.filter(item => {
        if (typeof item === 'number') {
            return item;
        }
    })    
    console.log(newArray);
}

filterOutStringfromArr([1,2,'A','B',123])
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally i would just use a normal array filter function and test the condition. let native array.filter function do the work for you. The below will filter the array and return a new array (not modify the existing array).

```js
function filterToArrayOfNumbers(arrayElement) {
    return typeof arrayElement === 'number';
}
console.log([1,2,'A','B',123].filter(filterToArrayOfNumbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr[i] = array[i]  // <------------  your issue
```

`i` is still being incremented, so when you are looking at your last number `123`, (index 4), it will set the new array at index 4 (leaving 2 and 3 empty)

rather than setting it explicitly, you can do `arr.push(array[i])`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push